# SQL Server job stuck even after restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent job stuck in "In Progress". It's a FULL backup that usually takes 30 minutes, but it's taking 7 hours and counting. I've restarted the Agent and then the whole OS and it still says "In Progress".

Is there any way to stop that?

If I run `select * from sys.dm_exec_requests`, I get 2 rows in "running" status, one says "SELECT", the other one "DBCC TABLE CHECK". And indeed the first step of the job is to run a Database Integrity check using Ola Hallengren's scripts.

Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)
>   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3  (Build
>   14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not using the GUID but using the T-SQL procedure:

[sp_stop_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-stop-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Could help resolve issues like the one you are having.

**Example:**

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name = 'enterjobnamehere'
```

Checking the [current running queries](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/) for any queries started by the agent and killing these could also help.

An example of adapting the script to find running queries started by the agent service:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_Sessions s
on req.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
WHERE [Program_Name] like 'SQLAgent%';
```